# \normalsize for \section, \subsection and \subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I tried to change the font size of titles using `titlesec`, I want all my document in normalsize, and I have an error. Please help me.

The error description is:

> ```
> Runaway argument?
> ./Thesis.tex:13: Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@ii was complete.
> <to be read again>
> ```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\hoffset}{.46cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{13.08pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-7mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{8mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4.6mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{8mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{\footnotesize{Text}\\ \footnotesize{Text}}%
 \chead{}%Vac
 \rhead{\footnotesize{Text}}
 \lfoot{\footnotesize{Text}\\       \footnotesize{Text}}%
 \cfoot{}
 \rfoot{\footnotesize{Text}}

 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

\begin{huge} \textbf{TEXT}\end{huge}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}
\begin{Large} \textbf{TEXT}\end{Large}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}
\begin{LARGE} \textbf{TEXT}\end{LARGE}\\
\vspace*{1.5cm}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]

\definecolor{rucv}{rgb}{.88,0.077,.1}
\definecolor{bucv}{rgb}{.001,.086,.55}

\draw(2.6,.58)node[color=bucv][font=\fontsize{20}{20}\sffamily\bfseries]{TEXT};

\draw(2.6,.3)node[color=bucv][font=\fontsize{20}{20}\sffamily\bfseries]{T\Large{EXT} \huge{T}\Large{EXT}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{LARGE} \textbf{"TEXT}\end{LARGE}\\
\vspace*{.5cm}
\begin{LARGE} \textbf{
TEXT"}\end{LARGE}\\
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{large} TEXT:\end{large}\\
\vspace*{.6cm}
\begin{LARGE} \textbf{TEXT}\end{LARGE}\\
\vspace*{.8cm}
\begin{large}Elaborado por:\end{large}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}
\begin{Large} \textbf{Text}\end{Large}\\
\vspace*{.8cm}
\begin{large}Text:\end{large}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{Large} \textbf{TEXT}\end{Large}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}
\begin{Large} \textbf{2013}\end{Large}\\
\vspace*{.4cm}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{TITLE}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}
\begin{easylist}
& Title
& Title
&& Subtitle
&&& Title
& Title
\end{easylist}

\subsubsection{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load `titlesec` with the `[tiny]` option you will get all headings in the text size (except `\chapter`). Also, you might want to look into using the `geometry` package for your margins.

Comment: Use `\titleformat*`, not `\titleformat`. (See the manual.)

Comment: I got it, with `tiny` and `*`, thanks you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you are doing (combining my and Torbjørn's comments.)

#### As a package option

The `titlesec` package has an option `[tiny]` which sets all headings (except `\chapter`) in the text font.

```
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
```

In this case you don't need any `\titleformat*` commands to change the size.

#### Use `\titleformat*`

There are two versions of the `\titleformat` command. The short form version (which is what you want here) is in fact `\titleformat*`; the long form version is `\titleformat`, which is why you got the error you did, since the command without the `*` is looking for up to 7 arguments.

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}
```

Comment: Or with `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}`